# homology of the complement of the union of two $2$-dim linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

I am working on the following problem - the homology of $X = \mathbb{R}^4 \setminus (X_1 \cup X_2)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two linear subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with dimension $2.$ I am not sure how to proceed. Should I go to the direction of finding what is this space $X$ homotopic to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown Do you mean that the M-V should be $\cdots H_n(\mathbb{R}^4\backslash X_1 \cap \mathbb{R}^4\backslash X_2) \rightarrow H_n(\mathbb{R}^4\backslash X_1)\oplus H_n(\mathbb{R}^4\backslash X_2) \rightarrow H_n(\mathbb{R}^4 \backslash (X_1 \cap X_2)) \cdots$? But what is $H_n(\mathbb{R}^4\backslash X_2)$ and $H_n(\mathbb{R}^4\backslash (X_1 \cap X_2))$?

Comment: @TylerDegruttola : Standard usage in MathJax and LaTeX is $A\setminus B$ rather than $A\backslash B.$ The former has the spacing appropriate to a binary operation symbol. With the latter it's as if you saw $3{+}5$ instead of $3+5.$ (Although I have come to prefer $A\smallsetminus B.$) $\qquad$

Comment: @TylerDegruttola $\Bbb R^4\setminus \mathrm{subspace}$ deformation retract to the unit sphere in the complement of the subspace

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks! lesson learnt!

Comment: @PeterFranek thanks! do you mean that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have dimension 2, $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus X_1 \sim S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus (X_1 \cap X_2) \sim S^2$ if $X_1 \cap X_2 \ne \emptyset$ and $X_1 \ne X_2$?

Comment: And if $X_1 \cap X_2 \ne \emptyset$, we $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^3$ because the relevant part of MV reduces to the short exact sequences $0 \rightarrow H_0(X) \rightarrow H_0(S^1) \oplus H_0(S^1) (\mathbb{Z}^2) \rightarrow H_0(S^2) (\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow 0$ and $0 \rightarrow H_2(S^2) (\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H_1(X) \rightarrow H_1(S^1) \oplus H_1(S^1) (\mathbb{Z}^2) \rightarrow H_1(S^2) (0)$. Am I right? Thank you for your patience! I just started to learn algebraic topology!

Comment: $X_1\cap X_2=\{0\}$ has (in generic case) dimension zero and then $\Bbb R^4\setminus \mathrm{point}\simeq S^3$.

Comment: @PeterFranek shouldn't $X_1 \cap X_2$ have three possible scenarios with dimensions 0, 1, 2 respectively?

Comment: @TylerDegruttola Yes, that's right.